# Node.js Formidable :: How to parse form 'multipart/form-data' with (php convention) array fields

Tags: node.js, parsing, formidable

[image]

Getting `req.body` blank and when I parse with formidable, it makes key and value like:

```
key : filter[phone] 
value : 978200000

key : filter[name] 
value : Shubham
```

Comment: When you console that then you will see `{}` but still you will able to use in code.

Comment: no. it does not show multipart form data in json object, but if i send data in raw format, bodyparser parses it in json object.

Answer (score 0):

Though there were some hacks & fixes for certain scenarios, the case of your question was [a continuing bug in Formidable](https://github.com/node-formidable/formidable/issues/620) which is fixed now: release `2.0.0-canary.20200504.1`.

All you need to do is to turn on the option `multiples` when you're creating an instance of formidable.

For example, assuming you're receiving the request (`req`) via [express](https://expressjs.com), you can do something like this:

```
const formidable = require('formidable');

const form = formidable({ multiples: true });

var inputFields = {};

form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
  if (err) {
    next(err);
    return;
  }
  inputFields = fields;
});
```

As in Javascript (**unlike** PHP) [arrays are more literal representation stacks](https://javascript.info/array) and objects are the goto way of storing everything, the `inputFields` which have string key value will be returned as object. So, for your example, `inputFields` will contain the following property:

```
filter {
  phone: '978200000',
  name: 'Shubham',
}
```

Also to be noted, formidable in the above mentioned way returns **string**.